# Infinite Power Tower approximation: float error?

Tags: exponentiation, approximation, tetration, power-towers

[Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oynvgkvw7s) appears to plot it falsely using the $x^y = y$ definition, curving backwards. I've included a 50x exponent for comparison, which suggests no values flowing left in $x$-axis due to float error - but not so sure of the approximation method used to generate $(x, y)$ pairs for $x^y = y$.

Is Desmos' approximation method known? Alternatively, what's an example method which'd yield the generated plot? Or is what's shown a valid "alternative solution" (despite it rendering $f(x)=x\uparrow \infty$ a non-function)?

---

[image]

Note red nears $x=1$ as $y \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Why do you say it is false ? Because given $x^y=y$ you get: $\log(x)\cdot y = \log(y)\implies \log(x)=\frac{\log(y)}{y}\underset{y\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0\implies x\to 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the $x^y=y$ plot by Desmos.  The curve really does double back with respect to $x$ when $y$ goes above $e\approx 2.71828$.  For instance, if we try $x=\sqrt2$ then we have both $(\sqrt2)^2=2$ and $(\sqrt2)^4=4$, so the curve should pass through $(\sqrt2,2)$ and then double back to catch $(\sqrt2,4)$.  If you look near the right side of the left plot, just to the left of the nose, you see that the red curve actually hits both of these points.

If you meant to plot the limiting value of the power tower, it follows **only part of the red curve, up to the nose at $y =e$**.  Beyond that the limit shoots up to infinity and the limiting power tower curve then looks like the blue one.  It does not bend back because it can't; the reversed direction of the red curve above $y=e$ corresponds to the fixed point becoming unstable so the power tower cannot converge there. Thus the red and blue curves diverge not because the red curve is wrong (which isn't true) but because the limiting behavior stops following the red curve.  **The limiting value of $x$ is $\exp(1/e)\approx 1.445$**.

Look to the left and you see the curves diverge again.  This is because another form of instability, by oscillating instead of blowing up, sets in when $y$ drops below $1/e$.  Again this causes the power tower to fail to converge; in this case **the lower limit for convergence is $x=\exp(-e)\approx 0.066$**.

This latter, oscillatory instability is not evident in any feature of the $x^y=y$ curve itself.  But if we go to Desmos and plot the doubly iterated form -- $x^{x^y}=y$ -- we find there is an extra branch that looks like a badly drawn parabola when $x<\exp(-e)$.  The power tower oscillates between the upper and lower parts of the "parabola", instead of trying to find the unstable fixed point of $x^y=y$ in this region.  Thus whereas the "blow-up" instability for large $y$ is seen as the $x^y=y$ curve doubling back, the oscillating instability for small $x,y$ appears instead as that curve getting walled off.

Comment: I don't follow; so the power tower isn't a _function_? Two outputs for one input violates the definition. Yet we can express it as an $f(x) = ...$ - I suppose it's to do with being unable to do so via finite arithmetic.

Comment: No, I did not say that.  The full _red curve_ is not a function.  If you keep the base low enough to avoid the power tower blowing up you get a function, but the function covers only _part_ of the red curve.

Comment: "Base"? Isn't the base (all of) the exponent(s)? There's only one input, $x$, no other degree of freedom. Even agreeing, if "keeping low" means $x < \text{const}$, then the red curve shouldn't exist, as it *is* for the "low" $x$. If $x^y = y$ _introduces_ a second degree of freedom by treating $x$ in the base and $y$ in the exponent as distinct, then the supposed equivalence to the infinite power tower appears to invalidate itself - as the original has only one d.o.f.

Comment: Yes, the base is the exponents too.  I use the word "base" to describe the input to the power tower.

Comment: "fixed points" and "stability" make sense in context of dynamic systems; all I see is a function, which is supposed to map one $x$ to one $y$. By same logic we represent the tower with $x^y = y$, $x^{x^y}=y$ should be the same, yet it isn't - so there appear to be some if's / conditions under which the _relation_ $x^y = y$ is equivalent to the infinite power tower _function_.

Comment: Unless... I missed the actual answer to my question that was due more emphasis: "it follows the red curve as far as the nose at $y=e$". So that _is_ "the condition"; the relation only represents the function up to that point, not beyond. Then we were both right. Worth restructuring the answer a bit or adding italics etc for emphasis - I'll accept.